# What is the best way to avoid spammers registering to my blog?

Tags: users, user-registration, spam

I would like to be able to easily control who registers to my blog because recently I had tons of spam users registering.
I came accross the plugin Stop Spammer Registrations, but i'm not sure it is reliable enough and I would also like to have a full log of every user who was rejected by the plugin/service.
Is there any good alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a HUGE fan of the [Bad Behavior](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bad-behavior/) plugin:

> Bad Behavior complements other link
>   spam solutions by acting as a
>   gatekeeper, preventing spammers from
>   ever delivering their junk, and in
>   many cases, from ever reading your
>   site in the first place. This keeps
>   your site's load down, makes your site
>   logs cleaner, and can help prevent
>   denial of service conditions caused by
>   spammers.

We started using Bad Behavior on our tech blog and noticed an immediate reduction of spam, as shown below.

[image: Bad Behavior activated on January 14]

Here is our full article on Bad Behavior: http://www.techerator.com/2010/05/significantly-reduce-website-spam-with-bad-behavior/

Comment: sounds great. Does it work against a db? does it log which  spammers were blocked?

Comment: Yes you can view Bad Behavior blocked logs under Tools --> Bad Behavior in WordPress. The logs are very detailed and contain explanations on why the offender was blocked. Be warned: it's a little creepy seeing all the sleezy scripts trying to access your site.

Comment: I installed it and even entered the http:BL Access Key. I already have 10 blocks from the last 10 minutes but some spammers were still able to pass through.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and cheapest way is to signup for Akismet.com, which is operated by Automattic (team behind WP.com). You name your price...you can pay zero or whatever you want for it. You'll need to install their plugin and signup for an API key at the Akismet site. The whole process it will take you like 5 minutes.

It will wipe out virtually all spam.

Another way is to install a Captcha plugin like Math Reloaded that will add a math question within the comments form. Unfortunately not all WP themes have been updated with the new comments framework so sometimes the captcha area appears below the submit button.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer my question because my main concern is spammers registering to my blog and not comments.
I'm not sure Akismet is intended to take care of registration, and if it does, then it's not really working for me because I had it installed from the very beginning and still many spammers are able to subscribe. Thanks for the answer anyway.